# How to convert a double [][] (jagged array) to a double[,] (matrix) in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

The following code works to convert a 'jagged array', i.e., double[][] to a matrix double[,].

```
static T[,] To2D<T>(T[][] source)
{
    try
    {
        int FirstDim = source.Length;
        int SecondDim = source.GroupBy(row => row.Length).Single().Key; //     throws InvalidOperationException if source is not rectangular

        var result = new T[FirstDim, SecondDim];
        for (int i = 0; i < FirstDim; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < SecondDim; ++j)
                result[i, j] = source[i][j];

        return result;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The given jagged array is not   rectangular.");
    } 
}
```

I would like to know how to do the inverse, that is, convert from double[,] to double[][].

Answer (score 4):

In a first step, you can only create the first level array. Then you need to create the second level arrays one by one:

```
var result = new T[FirstDim][];
for (int i = 0; i < FirstDim; i++) {
    var a = new T[SecondDim];
    result[i] = a;
    for (int j = 0; j < SecondDim; j++) {
        a[j] = source[i,j];
    }
}
```

Even if the resulting jagged array is rectangular, there is no shortcut to this procedure, because every row can in theory point to an array of different length (or even be `null`). This is why it is called jagged array.

Note that every `result[i]` is initialized to `null` when the array is created with `new T[size][]`.

Se also: [Jagged Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the optimized extensions:

```
static class extensions
{
    public static T[][] toJagged<T>(this T[,] source)
    {
        int rows = source.GetLength(0);
        int columns = source.GetLength(1);
        int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf<T>();
        var result = new T[rows][];

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            var temp = new T[columns];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(source, r * columns * size, temp, 0, columns * size);
            result[r] = temp;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static T[,] to2D<T>(this T[][] source)
    {
        int rows = source.Length;
        int columns = source.Select(i => i == null ? 0 : i.Length).Max(); // the longest row
        var result = new T[rows, columns];
        int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf<T>();

        int offset = 0;
        foreach(var row in source)
        {
            if (row != null)
                Buffer.BlockCopy(row, 0, result, offset * size, row.Length * size);

            offset += columns;
        }
        return result;
    }
} // end of class extensions
```

Sample use and test:

```
double[,] d2 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
double[][] dj = d2.toJagged();
Debug.Print(string.Join(", ", dj.SelectMany(i => i))); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

int[][] ij = { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 6, 7, 8, 9 } };
int[,] i2 = ij.to2D();
Debug.Print(string.Join(", ", i2.Cast<int>())); // 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

These work without using pinvoke:

```
   static T[][] ToJag<T>(T[,] source)
    {
        try
        {
            int FirstDim = source.GetLength(0);  // rows
            int SecondDim = source.GetLength(1); // cols

            var result = new T[FirstDim][];   // only acceptable syntax ???
            for (int i = 0; i < FirstDim; ++i)
            {
                result[i] = new T[source.GetLength(1)];  // just for columns
                for (int j = 0; j < SecondDim; ++j)
                {
                    result[i][j] = source[i, j];
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid operation error.");
        }
    }
    static T[,] To2D<T>(T[][] source)
    {
        try
        {
            int FirstDim = source.Length;
            int SecondDim = source.GroupBy(row => row.Length).Single().Key; // throws InvalidOperationException if source is not rectangular

            var result = new T[FirstDim, SecondDim];
            for (int i = 0; i < FirstDim; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < SecondDim; ++j)
                    result[i, j] = source[i][j];

            return result;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The given jagged array is not rectangular.");
        }
    }
```

NB: Need Using System.Linq for T[,] To2D(T[][] source) to work properly.